# WINUI3 - Customize TitleBar

Tags: c++, winui-3

Just a quick clarification needed regarding .setTitleBar() usage.

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window
    
    x:Class="Wrath.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Wrath"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    
    <Grid>
        <!-- ... -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="CustomTitleBar">Custom title text</TextBlock>

        <!-- ... -->


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cpp*

```
MainWindow::ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar(true);
MainWindow::SetTitleBar(?);
```

**How do I reference the xaml element as argument in the SetTitleBar function?**

This is based on the example (only for .cs) provided from:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.settitlebar?view=winui-3.0

Answer (score 0):

As of project reunion 0.8, I have been able to successfully set the titlebar as follows:

In your MainWindow.xaml.cpp file:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this->ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar(true);
    this->SetTitleBar(AppTitleBar());        
}
```

In your MainWindow.xaml file somewhere:

```
<Grid x:Name="AppTitleBar">
    ... titlebar code goes here        
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of the 1.0 release this is the preferred way.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.settitlebar?view=winui-3.0

```html
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <!-- ... -->

        <TextBlock x:Name="CustomTitleBar">Custom title text</TextBlock>

        <!-- ... -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

with

```html
private MainWindow m_window;

protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    m_window = new MainWindow();

    m_window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;
    m_window.SetTitleBar(m_window.CustomTitleBar);

    m_window.Activate();
}
```